# How to get Imageview image most available color?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I have created an android layout having an imageview.I need to set the layout background color using a color inside imageview image.anyone have any idea of how to do it in Android Java ?

Comment: "Using color inside imageview image" is Your `ImageView` just a color or You have to get a color from a specific place in the image?

Comment: Inside imageview have an image and i need to get a color widely spread in image not from a specific place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel#Drawables

and using [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) you can achieve it.

However, there is an easy solution for this, if you don't mind to wait some sec to get the color.

```
public static int getDominantColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, true);
    final int color = newBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
    newBitmap.recycle();
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Is there way to get the center color of image

Answer (score 0):

***To add background image to JFrame, use the getImage() method of the Image class −***

```
 Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("F:\\Smartgirl.jpg");
```

*Now, draw the image −*

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
```

**The following is an example to add Background Image to JFrame −
Example**

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import java.awt.Toolkit;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
   public class SwingDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("F:\\Smartgirl.jpg");
   public SwingDemo() throws IOException {
  this.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
     }
  });
   pack();
   setVisible(true);
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  new SwingDemo();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Actually im doing it in Android Platform